# Improving upload speed by sending chunk of bytes

Tags: android, http, networking, file-upload

I'm developing an android video uploading app and uploading large amounts of video is a problem, I get different type of exception sometimes (host not resolved, pipe broken), I do a multipart POST but I have a feeling if I upload chunk of bytes one at at time that'll increase upload speed as well as solve connection timeout and these type of problems.

Answer (score 1):

If you have control of the server, think about using raw [TCP/IP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tcp/ip) via [sockets](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/Socket.html) instead of http: http adds considerable overhead. In some circumstances, going down to the udp layer instead can improve performance even further: but be aware of the complexity of ensuring delivery and sequencing yourself.